# Como represento um numero negativo no Python

Tags: python

Como posso usar o if em um numero negativo?
Estou fazendo exercicios de Python, e queria saber como representar. O programa recebe um numero do usuario, e tenho que usar um 'if' caso esse numero seja negativo, como posso realizar?

Exemplo:

```
if variavel for negativa:
   print("Alguem me ajuda")
```

Comment: Supondo que a variável já contém um valor numérico, basta fazer `if variavel < 0: print('negativo')`. Se for uma string (por exemplo, obtida usando `input` para ler o que o usuário digitou), basta converter antes: `variavel = float(input('digite um número'))` e depois faça o `if`

Answer (score -2):

Seria variável menor ou igual 0, ou caso tenha que ser um número menor que 0 e não 0, poderia usar o < no lugar de <=

```py
    # pede variavel e converte para inteiro
    variavel = int(input('numero:'))

    #if variavel for menor ou igual 0
    if variavel <= 0:
      print("Alguem me ajuda")
```

Answer (score -3):

Supondo que a variável já contém um valor numérico, basta fazer
if variavel < 0:
print('negativo')

Se for uma string (por exemplo, obtida usando input para ler o que o usuário digitou), basta converter antes:
variavel = float(input('digite um número'))
e depois faça o if

reposta do @hkotsubo está correta